# Matching patterns for awk script

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to count the numbers of words that starts and ends with "**de**" but I could only make it count the words that has **de**. Example

My input file

```
dende
detail
DEnaDE
de.de
de
```

My code:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
/^de/&&/de/
```

Results:

```
dende
de.de
detail
de
```

I am suppose to get **dende**,**de.de**,**DenaDe**,**de**. I used the operator && in my code so I don't get why it doesn't work. Can anyone correct me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please elaborate why line `de` is not there in output that also satisfy the condition correct?'

Comment: Oh right my bad. It's suppose to be there.

Comment: You need to anchor the second re to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for IGNORECASE:

```
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^de/ && /de$/' file
dende
DEnaDE
de.de
de
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{lc=tolower($0)} (lc ~ /^de/) && (lc ~ /de$/)' file
dende
DEnaDE
de.de
de
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also use `grep`

```
$ grep -ix 'de\|de.*de' ip.txt
dende
DEnaDE
de.de
de

$ grep -cix 'de\|de.*de' ip.txt
4
```

- `-i` to ignore case
- `x` to match only whole line
- `-c` to print total count instead of matching lines
- `de\|de.*de` match `de` as whole line *or* match line starting with `de` and ending with `de`

If `\|` is not supported, use `grep -ixE 'de|de.*de'` or `grep -ixE 'de(.*de)?'` or `grep -ix -e 'de' -e 'de.*de'` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^[Dd][eE]/&&/[Dd][eE]$/' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '/^[Dd][eE]/&&/[Dd][eE]$/{count++}  END{print count}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you. Is there a difference between /^[DdeE].*[DdeE]$/ and /^[DdeE]/&&/[DdeE]$/?

Comment: Not really in this case, you could use a single regex just fine.